How to Retest Without Losing Previous Results in Azure Test Plans?
I’ve already set up my Test Suite, Test Plans, and Test Cases. However, I’m trying to figure out how to run the same tests again while keeping the results from the previous runs intact. Any tips on how I can achieve this without overwriting past execution data?
I could not find any duplicate button.

Hope this MS Doc helps you that has the information on copying/cloning the test plans, cases in Azure DevOps.

Show what you tried or Show some screenshots whether you created the test cases, plans or not.
